# Drawing over a constantly changing picture

Tags: java, paintcomponent

I'm trying to program a slot machine. 
So, i made a `JPanel`, in which i override the `paintComponent()` method.

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;

    g2.drawImage(backImage, 0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight(),null); // Background
    if(slot1On) //Slot Machine
    {
        g2.drawImage(getSlot1(masterCount), 26, 50,slotSizeW,slotSizeH, null);
    }
    else
    {
        g2.drawImage(getSlot1(slot1Pos), 26, 50,slotSizeW,slotSizeH, null);
    }
    g2.setColor(Color.WHITE); // Text
    g2.setFont(new Font(lblAction.getFont().getName(),Font.BOLD,16));
    g2.drawString("Press Space to stop the wheel!", 32, 25);
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<3;i++) // Lines on the slot machine
    {
        g2.setColor(new Color(0,0,0,0.9f));
        g2.fillRect(27+ 12 * i + slotSizeW * i, 50 + slotSizeH/2-1, slotSizeW, 3);
        g2.fillRect(28+ 12 * i + slotSizeW * i, 50 +slotSizeH/2-4, 3,9);
        g2.fillRect(22+ 12 * i + slotSizeW * (i +1) , 50 +slotSizeH/2-4, 3, 9);
        for(j=0;j<8;j++)
        {
            if(j < 4)
            {
                g2.setColor(new Color(0,0,0,0.9f - j * 0.1f));
                g2.fillRect(26 + 12 * i + slotSizeW * i, 50 + j * 4, slotSizeW, 4); 
            }
            else
            {
                g2.setColor(new Color(0,0,0,0.9f - (8 - j) * 0.1f));
                g2.fillRect(26+ 12 * i + slotSizeW * i, 50 + slotSizeH - (8 - j) * 4,    slotSizeW, 4); 
            }
        }
    }  
}
```

However, everything i try to draw after the slot machine isn't displayed as long the slot wheel are moving, as shown in the image:

[image]

So, why aren't they displaying correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
super.paintComponent(g);
//the rest of your painting here
}
```

Comment: The super call doesnt fix my problem.

Comment: @Daemoth maybe providing an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) would help for better help sooner

Comment: Huh... i was able to fix it. For no apparent reason, doing a .getSubImage() from my slot picture was causing my problems, even though the subImage wasnt even used... Oh well, thx for your time.

Comment: @Daemoth Glad you got it fixed please not though it is best practice to call super paintComponent on your JPanel